# Rails: about yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I saw some code in a **Rails v2.3** app.

In `layout/car_general.html.erb` (this view is called by a method in cars_controller) , I saw the code:

```
<body>
    <%= yield %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.2.min' %>

    <% javascript_tag do %>
      <%= yield :jstemplates %>
          var some_car = new Object;
      <%= yield :some_car %>
    <% end -%>
</body>
```

Two questions to ask:

1. Where can I find the yield content of the first <%=yield%> under `<body>`.
2. Is it a rails specific way to include js code in a view by using 
   `<%= yield :jstemplates %>` and what about `<%= yield :some_car %>` , is it point to a view or just to show the value of `some_car`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Without any arguments, yield will render the template of the current controller/action. So if you're on the `cars/show` page, it will render `views/cars/show.html.erb`.

When you pass yield an argument, it lets you define content in your templates that you want to be rendered outside of that template. For example, if your `cars/show` page has a specific html snippet that you want to render in the footer, you could add the following to your show template and the `car_general` layout:

**show.html.erb:**

```
<% content_for :footer do %>
  This content will show up in the footer section
<% end %>
```

**layouts/car_general.html.erb**

```
<%= yield :footer %>
```

The Rails Guide has a good section on using yield and content_for: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

The API documentation for [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) is helpful too and has some other examples to follow. Note that it's for Rails 3.1.1 , but this functionality has not changed much since 2.3, if at all and should still apply for 3.0.x and 3.1.x.