# Difference between Render and Render Partial and Yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have read it from the Rails guides, Have looked at Micheal Hartel book and now reading it from Rails View book but still I get confused :(

There is a `_footer.html.erb`  file so it is a "partial"  and in the code it has written:

```
<%=render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

so my understanding is that when it sees this, goes and insert the HTML for footer file in here. Ok...
Now a few pages later it is saying:

```
<%= render partial: 'activitiy_items/recent' %>
```

so WHY this time we have the word "partial" in here but we didn't have it in the previous one?

And there somewhere else I see `<%= yield :sidebar %>`

So this `yield` also insert HTML in its place? Well wasn't it what `render` was doing?

I was hoping if another programmer instead of books explains this to me maybe I get it this time:)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## `render` & `render partial:`

- `render 'some_view'` is a shorthand for `render partial: 'some_view'`.
- `render file: 'view'` will look for a file `view.html.erb` and NOT `_view.html.erb` (`.erb` or any other renderer you use)
- `render` can pass local variables for the partial if you do not use collections or layouts, like

  ```
   render 'some/path/to/my/partial', custom_var: 'Hello'
  ```

- [Passing local variable guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)
- [Rendering the default case](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

## `yield` & `content_for`

- `yield` is typically used in **layouts**. It tells Rails to put the content for this block at *that* place in the layout.
- When you do `yield :something` associated with `content_for :something`, you can pass a block of code (view) to display where the `yield :something` is placed (see example below).

---

**A small example about yield:**

In your layout:

```
<html>
<head>
 <%= yield :html_head %>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
   <%= yield :sidebar %>
 </div>
</body>
```

In one of your view:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  This content will show up in the sidebar section
<% end %>

<% content_for :html_head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hello World!");
  </script>
<% end %>
```

This will produce the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hello World!");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
   This content will show up in the sidebar section
 </div>
</body>
```

---

**Posts that might help**:

- [Embedded Ruby -- Render vs. Yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299851/embedded-ruby-render-vs-yield)
- [Render @object and locals vs render :partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990539/render-object-and-locals-vs-render-partial)
- [Rails: about yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848020/rails-newbie-about-yield)

**Links to documentation & guides**:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Comment: Further to his answer look at this for reference please: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Ok thanks but still whats the difference between Render and Yield in a layout?  They both insert HTML ?

Comment: So both Render and Yield are rendering HTML and inserting it?

Comment: `yield :something` will call `render` on the block of code provided in a `content_for :something`. `render` will just produce the HTML when it is called.

Comment: `yield` is a Ruby keyword - it is not specific to Rails. I had a hard time wrapping my head around it when I came from Java and PHP a year ago.

Comment: `render :partial 'some/path/to/my/partial'` should be `render partial: 'some/path/to/my/partial'`

Comment: You can pass variables to render without :partial, at least in Rails 4.  Eg.  render 'some/path/to/my/partial', custom_var: 'Hello'.   See 'Rendering the default case' here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Answer (score 4):

## About render , render :partial and yield

- **render :template and render :partial are two files in rails..**

  ---

  render :template are mostly created according to an action with syntax demo.html.erb

  render :partial are reuseable and called from different views , are shared among many pages in application and syntax is  _demo.html.erb
- **yield and render..**

  ---

Yield is a way to call a block of code with its output but render will include a partial page template where it is called.  In rails yield is mostly used in layout whereas render is used in actions or their templates

Comment: This is grossly Incorrect regarding syntax of render :partial - render :partial is an expanded form and accepts local variables as MrYoshiji wrote above ..  The "\_" is for partials that are NOT actions .. all actions (defined in controller) are written without the prefix ("_") -- You can call render on any defined singular/plural model name using the rails convetions