# Difference between render :template and render :partial in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

i was a bit experimenting in my rails app.i tried to use `render :template` in `erb` file .i got an error.After that i changed it to `render :partial` and it ran successfully as i was expecting.i am wondering why i got this error.i tried to google but i got no major source that points out the difference between the two.Does the two behave differently at controller level and view level.if yes then why?

Comment: I think read the following link you get your answer.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: thanks @urjit rajgor..i will go through and clear my concepts.

Comment: I think the main difference between `render` and `render partial` is  `render` does not accept additional local variables but `render partial` does. For more info you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822775/difference-between-render-and-render-partial-and-yield

Answer (score 4):

The render :partial looks for the file name to be proceeded by an underscore while the template does not:

```
  render partial:'example'
```

looks for **_example.html.erb**

while:

```
 render template: 'example'
```

looks for **example.html.erb**

There may be other issues, but odds are this is why you recieved the error based on it working once you made the change. Hope this helps...