# Change Tab name From Foundation - Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I've added Foundation to my Rails site, but now the tab in my browser is displaying

```
Foundation - Rails
```

How would I change that to my site's title ?

Comment: `app/views/layout/application.html.{erb|haml}`, search do the `<title>` tag which is in the `<head>` tag

Comment: There's a helpful tutorial from the RailsApps project on [Foundation and Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-foundation.html) which provides details. You can use the [Rails Layout](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout) gem to set up Foundation correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your application layout if you ran `rails g foundation:install` and overwrote the layout

Comment: Perfect - thanks. It was in     `<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>` I simply changed the "foundation-rails" to my site's title.

Comment: A post about content_for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822775/difference-between-render-and-render-partial-and-yield/16822915#16822915