# Usage of render and render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For rendering a partial I can use

`render 'partial_name'` or `render partial: 'partial_name'`

I came to know that `render` is the shorthand syntax of `render partial` and render will not accept additional local variables for the partial from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16822915/3185510)

I would like to know if there is any performance issue when using `render` instead of `render partial`

Comment: You should look at both methods in the rails source and report back the source code. We can help you look at the difference but at least provide a little more research...

Answer (score 1):

**In Rails, the `render` action**

> "Renders the content that will be returned to the browser as the
>   response body."

It is possible to render an action, text, the contents of a file, and other things, including a partial view.

```
render :action => "Create"
render :file => "/path/to/file/foo.erb", :layout => true, :status => 404
render :partial =>...
```

Using the `partial` label explicitly, disambiguates the render action for Rails ActionController.

As far as performance, I haven't done the test to confirm, but I think it's reasonable to expect it is more efficient to use `render :partial` for the above reasons.

When I'm looking for the nuts & bolts underlying Rails logic, [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) is an excellent detailed technical reference.