# Ruby on Rails partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone help me out with the following?
I have a partial view named `_menu.html.erb` inside a **shared** folder in views folder. I am trying to render this view inside my pages like so

```
<%= render "shared/menu" %>
```

But i am getting the following error.

```
Missing partial shared/_menu with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your partial located at `app/views/shared/_menu.html.erb`?

// Nevermind, stupid me. You already gave that answer in your question.

Comment: try to replace your line with this   <%= render :partial => "/shared/menu" %>

Comment: Thanks mokariya2 thats worked. But why? Is there any difference between render partial and just render?

Comment: `render` can also take a full template as argument. You can, of course, specify whether it's a `partial`, what `layout` to use and other stuff.
Do you by any chance have another file called `menu.html.erb` within the same folder? That might've caused the issue.

Comment: @TKarropoulos read this hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822775/difference-between-render-and-render-partial-and-yield?lq=1

Comment: No I did not have any file called menu.html.erb. Anyway thanks for your help! Have a nice day!

Comment: You most welcome. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `menu.html.erb`

here

```
app/views/shared/_menu.html.erb
```

and then render this with this line

```
<%= render :partial => "/shared/menu" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use just "render" with an argument, it's excpecting an ActiveRecord object, and will look for the "show" partial of this object, like this :

```
<%= render @user %> #this will render the "user/show" partial for @user
```

You can render a classical partial like this (without `locals` if you don't need any arguments) :

```
<%= render partial: "shared/menu", locals: {my_arg: my_val} %>
```